# Why my docker-compose volume doesn't detect changement

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, nestjs

I'm learning docker & docker-compose i have a vueJS App and a nestjs api that i try to dockerize

what i want to do is to setup volume so when i'll change something in the file i don't have to rebuild again this is what i did:

Docker-compose.yml (in a different directory)

```
services:
  front:
    build: ../ecommerce-front # I tried to add :/app but my container doesn't find app/package.json
    ports: 
        - "8080:8080"
    volumes: 
      - ../ecommerce-front/src
    
  back:
    build: ../ecommerce-back
    ports:
        - "3000:3000"
    depends_on: 
      - mysql
    volumes: 
      - ../ecommerce-back/src
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: tools
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
```

backend Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14 AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build


FROM node:10-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app ./
CMD ["npm", "run", "start:dev"]
```

i have no error, my services is running well but when i make some changes to my back there's no changement in the container

What did i do wrong ?

Thanks by advance

Comment: are your files on the host mounted into the container or do you develop in the container? also what does the start:dev script do? I'm assuming nodemon or something similar?

Comment: the local project is in my computer and start:dev just start project after npm run build ":dev" add --watch to the nest start

Comment: not touched vue before but I'm assuming its using webpack on the backend. in any case... to mount a volume for dev on the host try ammding your compose file so the volumes are mounted with the format `hostdir:containerdir`

Comment: doing this youre likely to run into issues with your node modules so you'll also need to use a docker volume to protect them when mounting host files. just add a line below your volume mount something like `- /container/path/to/node_modules`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to richardsefton it seems i needed to add node_modules as volume to my two services like this:

```
 volumes: 
      - ../ecommerce-front:/app
      - '/app/node_modules'
    volumes: 
      - ../ecommerce-back:/app
      - '/app/node_modules'
```

Comment: This is an explicit directive to Docker that the `node_modules` directory contains user data that needs to be preserved across container restarts, and changes in the underlying image should be ignored.  It will have the effect of causing your container to ignore changes to the `package.json` file.

Comment: yeah you would need to build the container if you add new modules. or exec into it and install the module manually